# Glide not Loading image from StorageReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have problem when loading image from StorageReference to ImageView using Glide 4.9.0 (latest).

It's stuck on PlaceHolder..
When I try to put the downloadable url of my ref, it's working..

```
StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("myImage")

//It's not working
Glide.with(mContext)
   .load(ref)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_circle)
   .error(R.drawable.ic_loading_circle)
   .into(mImageView);

//It's working
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl)
    {
        Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(downloadUrl.toString())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_circle)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_loading_circle)
            .into(mImageView);
    }
});
```

I didn't see any error using try-catch, I already put Internet permission in Manifest. Other image from drawable are working also

Note: My firebase is used by 2 apps, the first app is working without any problem with Glide, but this 2nd app got unknown problem.

any solution or alternative? because using getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener to get URI are so slow

Comment: "any alternative from Glide?" Asking for a technology recommendation is off-topic on Stack Overflow. But if you put that question in your favorite search engine, you'll find plenty of alternatives. That said: the need to call `getDownloadUrl()` is a Firebase API and has nothing to do with Glide, so most other libraries will also need that step

Comment: One more thing left for you to do before Glide can do the magic. Loader registration. [See snippet](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/d267a10ce8e84cb028af94064c4a291c2b32eef9/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/referencecode/storage/MyAppGlideModule.java) [Read it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution working for you is the correct solution. I did things the same way.

```
profileListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            if (ProfileFragment.this.getActivity() != null)
                Glide.with(ProfileFragment.this.getActivity())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                        .circleCrop()
                        .into(photoPhoto);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

If you are finding this thing slow just enable offline persistence in firebase.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Before calling any FirebaseDatabase instance when app open.

Firebase manages the syncing very efficiently.

Note:- Whenever you find any random anomaly calling snapshot during developing the app, try clearing the data of the app or reinstalling.

Worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Glide` support `StorageReference` it is different protocol, but you can use FirebaseUI that support this, and uses behind the scene `Glide`library.

[FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

The answers above did not work for me.

In Glide `4.8.0`,this is what worked for me:

1. First make sure you have the following in your app `build.gradle`

   `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.2'`

   `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'`

   `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'`

2.Then use the following code to load the image from storage reference

```
    DrawableCrossFadeFactory factory =
            new DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder().setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build();

    RequestOptions options =
            new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.your_progress_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_your_on_error_image);

    // Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
    // (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
    Glide.with(getAppContext())
            .load(item.reference)
            .transition(withCrossFade(factory))
            .apply(options)
            .into(holder.signatureImageView);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Using FirebaseUI you can quickly and easily download, cache, and
>   display images from Cloud Storage using our integration with Glide.
>
> First, add FirebaseUI to your app/build.gradle:
>
> dependencies {
>       // FirebaseUI Storage only
>       implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1' }

Then you can load images directly from Storage into an ImageView:

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

[Firebase Documentation for loading image directly via Glide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)